# keypress event not working in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a text box in my web-page. I want to prevent user from entering space without entering any character. I have this now.

```
    $('#DivisionName').bind('keypress', function(e) {
        if($('#DivisionName').text().length == 0){
            if (e.which == 32){//space bar
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        }
        else{
            alert("if not working");
        }
    });
```

This is my HTML

```
    <input maxLength=15 name="DivisionName" id="DivisionName" size=15>
```

When I run the code, it is allowing user to enter space without giving any character. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`text()` is use when div, span value. In case text box always use `val()`

Try this

```
$('#DivisionName').bind('keypress', function(e) {
    if($('#DivisionName').val().length == 0){
        if (e.which == 32){//space bar
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    }
    else{
        alert("if not working");
    }
});
```

You are not defining input type, so add `type="text"`

```
  <input type="text" maxLength=15 name="DivisionName" id="DivisionName" size=15>
```

Comment: It would be nice, if you can explain, what you have changed (from `text()` to `val`).

Comment: for getting values from form field use : val(); text() using for geting values from div tags etc as text. html() for as html

Answer (score 0):

try it like this :

```
$("#DivisionName").keypress(function() {
console.log("keypress called.");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to enslose your code into

```
$(function() {
// CODE
}
```

It works - check here: http://jsfiddle.net/Dufvg/

And yes ... Replace .text() with .val()

Answer (score 0):

[Working Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/2cYeu/9/)

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="DivisionName" />
```

**Javascript**

```
window.onload = function () {
    var inputEl = document.getElementById("DivisionName");
    inputEl.addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
        if (inputEl.value.length == 0) {
            if (e.keyCode == 32) {
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
 <input type="text" maxLength=15 name="DivisionName" id="DivisionName" size=15> 

$("#DivisionName").keypress(function(event) {
if($('#DivisionName').val().length == 0){
            if (e.which == 32){//space bar
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        }
        else{
            alert("if not working");
        }

});
```